# Set browserWindow Always on top, Even if Other Apps/Games are in fullscreen [Electron, Windows OS]

Tags: javascript, windows, electron

How do I let me electron app be ontop of other apps or games that are in fullscreen mode, like an overlay on Windows.

This `mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, "level");` works for most apps.

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window

I've checked the electron docs and tried every different 'level' none of them work in games that are fullscreen.

Code:

```
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, "level");


  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};
```

I'm currently testing this in League of Legends.
Changing video setting to borderless, the window shows, however changing to fullscreen, the electron window is no longer infront.

I know its possible, because Discord (made with electron) has an overlay that is shown in games that are set to fullscreen.

Comment: Words matter in this case, because the docs say: "`alwaysOnTop` Boolean (optional) - Whether the window should always stay on top of other windows. Default is false.". Note the word "windows" there, because full screen applications are not windowed. They're full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Overlays aren't possible in electron.js, since it only interacts with the standard win32 api.

If I recall correctly, discord uses a separate, lower level application for their overlays.

Comment: any clue which lower level application or library they use to interact with it? Struggling to find any information on it